# how do i delete transcripts automatically from assemblyai

Tags: python, api

I'm currently using cmd line to generate transcripts. How would i go abotu periodically deleting transcripts from their servers?

I'm currently using local python files

I need some kind of method i can automate that  excludes the last 10, ideally by ID count, or failing that by date somehow?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.assemblyai.com/docs/Models/speech_recognition#deleting-transcripts-from-the-api

It’s in their docs. But essentially:

```
# Retrieving transcript broken down into paragraphs
endpoint = f"https://api.assemblyai.com/v2/transcript/{transcript_id}"

# Make a DELETE request to the API endpoint with the headers
response = requests.delete(endpoint, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```